# Creating SqlView Layer with GeoServer Manager?

Tags: geoserver, sql, getfeatureinfo, geoserver-rest-api, geoserver-manager

I would like to register a new SQL view layer to GeoServer through the REST API, I am using geoserver-manager.

The registration is OK, the layer is working fine, except the WMS GetFeatureInfo, which returns:

```
"Operation on mixed SRID geometries".
```

If I manually set the SQL view's geometry column's SRID in the GeoServer administration page, it works fine.

But I cannot find any way to set it in the XML request. I'm sending the geometry info:

```
<geometry>
    <name>geom</name>
    <type>Point</type>
    <srid>4326</srid>
</geometry>
```

And the geometry attribute:

```
<attribute>
    <name>geom</name>
    <minOccurs>0</minOccurs>
    <maxOccurs>1</maxOccurs>
    <nillable>true</nillable>
    <binding>com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point</binding>
</attribute>
```

But I cannot set the attributes SRID and the geometry info is not enough.
The geometry attribute will be registered as SRID -1.

Is there an API call to refresh the layer fields?